# Nasa Worldwind: How do you fix these weird run time exceptions?

Tags: java, configuration, runtime, worldwind

Nasa Worldwind SDK has some examples that I wish to run. There are two ways I am trying to run the examples provided in the SDK:

1. Create an Eclipse project using the entire SDK source folder.

   - point to all the worldwind dependencies (*.jar and *.dll files)
   - Go to the folder with examples: src\gov\nasa\worldwind\examples.
   - Run the example ApplicationTemplate.java main.
2. Create an Eclipse project that is empty.

   - point to all the worldwind dependencies (*.jar and *.dll files)
   - point to worldwind.jar
   - Then copy the examples folder into my Eclipse project.
   - Refactor all the packages that are listed as gov.nasa.worldwind.examples to examples.
   - Run the example ApplicationTemplate.java main.

**When I do option (1.) I successfully compile/run with no errors.**

**When I do option (2.) I successfully compile but get run time errors:**

```
Apr 13, 2011 12:18:35 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind createComponent
SEVERE: Exception while creating World Wind component gov.nasa.worldwind.cache.BasicDataFileStore
Apr 13, 2011 12:18:35 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind createConfigurationComponent
SEVERE: Unable to create class for configuration key gov.nasa.worldwind.cache.BasicDataFileStore
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.WorldWindowGLCanvas.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Main2.main(Main2.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create class for configuration key gov.nasa.worldwind.cache.BasicDataFileStore
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind.createConfigurationComponent(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: gov.nasa.worldwind.exception.WWRuntimeException: Exception while creating World Wind component gov.nasa.worldwind.cache.BasicDataFileStore
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind.createComponent(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.cache.BasicDataFileStore.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Due to licensing and configuration management issues, I would STRONGLY PREFER to go with Option (2.). **Does anyone know how to fix these run time errors seen above?**

Comment: Hmm, it should be no problem with Option (2) in most cases unless something is missing during the translation. I will check this for you and reply a.s.a.p since I have tinkered with Worldwind libraries in the past few months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok..These are my **Eclipse** project steps under **Windows** environment:

1. Create a new **Eclipse** project (a blank
   project is fine as long as it has
   the `src` folder)
2. Create the `lib` folder under this
   project (under the root of the
   project folder)
3. Put required libraries and DLLs into
   the `lib` folder: `gluegen-rt.jar,
   jogl.jar, worldwind.jar, jogl.dll,
   gluegen-rt.dll, jogl_awt.dll,
   jogl_cg.dll`
4. copy the sample `HelloWorlWind.java`
   into the `src` folder
5. Add all JARs in the `lib` folder into
   the `Referenced Libraries` tree by
   right-clicking on each jar and
   select `Build Path > Add to Build
   Path`
6. Right-click on `jogl.jar` in the 
   `Referenced Libraries` tree and
   select `Build Path > Configure Build
   Path`. It will pop up `Properties`
   dialog box
7. In `Properties` dialog box, go to
   `Libraries tab` and expand
   `jogl.jar` tree
8. Select `Native library location` and
   click `Edit` button on the right. It
   will popup `Native Library Folder
   Configuration` dialog box.
9. Set the `lib` folder as the location
   path by clicking on `Workspace...`
   button.

Then, run `HelloWorlWind.java`. It will display the glorious Worldwind Earth without any exception!

Take note: a few Worldwind example apps don't terminate the JVM after you close the GUI window.

For the `ApplicationTemplate.java` to work, make sure to copy the required dependencies:

- ClickAndGoSelectListener.java
- LayerPanel.java

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems from doing exactly what you describe in option 2, it works fine. When using a freshly downloaded copy of the WorldWind Java source code, you should do an Ant Build it before using the WorldWind.jar file. The WorldWind.jar file is not always upto date and can cause conflicts when being used.

Basically what you describe from your actions is this: It works when it is using the source code, and that it fails when it is using the compiled code.

Comment: interesting... I will have to try what you suggest. I assumed that their build system forced the source and jar classes to be the same (i.e. prevent human error where your source code is different from the jar classes).